# Performance of methods for free(pointer)?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc, free

Both methods work but which one is the faster/performant in the case `ptr == NULL`?

```
void voo()
{    
  str *ptr = NULL;      

  // try to malloc memory and do something

  // leaving methode and free the memory 
  if(ptr != NULL)
  { 
    free(ptr);
    ptr = NULL;
  }
}
```

Do I need an `if` query at all if I leave the method? Is it not just as quick to give `free` the memory in any case?

```
void baa()
{    
  str *ptr = NULL;      

  // try to malloc memory and do something

  // leaving methode and free the memory 
  free(ptr);
  ptr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `free (ptr)` you mean, right?

Comment: Why are you tagging C++? You generally don't use `malloc`/`free` in C++, and in most cases like this you would not use dynamic allocation anyway.

Comment: The final `ptr = NULL` is also pointless (although the compiler should realise that and not generate any time-wasting code for it).

Comment: I've amended the question: exchanged `prt` for `ptr`. Do roll back if this was intentional.

Comment: @ crashmstr: Sure, in new code. I've got this problems at old and grown code. (More than 100.000 lines of code). I can't write every thing new!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From C standard, 7.20.3.2/2, if `ptr` is `NULL` then `free(ptr)` does nothing.

It's therefore pointless for you to check this, from both performance and superfluous code perspectives.

Comment: +1. Setting `ptr` to `NULL` right before it goes out of scope is also pointless, noisy and confusing.

Comment: Just to make it explicit: In general, setting a pointer to NULL after free'ing is fine. It's pointless here only because of the limited scope of `ptr`.

Comment: @oxygene Setting the freed pointer to null is usually pointless, since most of the time, it will immediately go out of scope.  (In C++, I would imagine that most uses of `delete` are in destructors, in which case, there's no point in setting the pointer to null.)  Finding all of the other pointers to the object, and setting them to null, might be useful.  If you can find an effective way of doing it.